# Accessing FTP server behind a proxy via command prompt in Windows 7

Tags: windows, cmd, proxy, ftp, port

I want to connect to the FTP server ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/merged/3B42RT from my command prompt in Windows 7.

It's always showing not connected.

I am running my PC behind proxy. I came to know about port error. Followed this solution [here](http://www.2x.com/configuring-the-windows-server-2008-r2-firewall-to-open-ports-for-2x-solutions/) about port forwarding but still no result.

Answer (score 11):

Windows built-in command-line `ftp.exe` client does not support connecting over a proxy. It also supports an active mode only, what makes it difficult to connect though proxy anyway (even if some transparent proxy solution is used).

You have to use a 3rd party command-line FTP client that supports a passive mode and a proxy.

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), you can use the following batch file (`.bat`):

```
WinSCP.com /command ^
    "open ftp://anonymous:dummy@trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/ -rawsettings ProxyMethod=3 ProxyHost=proxy ProxyUsername=username ProxyPassword=password" ^
    "cd /pub/merged/3B42RT" ^
    "ls" ^
    "exit"
```

See a [guide to scripting with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) and a [guide for converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

The above code is for an HTTP proxy. If you use a different proxy type, alter the `ProxyMethod` setting accordingly. See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings

Though easier is to configure the connection in WinSCP GUI and then have it [generate a script template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) for you.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: WinSCP absolutely rocks!